# Iterator for a container of a custom object

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

If I've built a class that I want to contain inside, for example a set, how would I iterate through said set? Could I say

```
 std::set<customObject>::iterator it
```

I thought I could do that, but I'm getting the following series of errors...

```
drawing.h:110: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘it = ((object*)this)->object::objects. std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin [with _Tp = object, _Alloc = std::allocator<object>]()’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_tree.h:225: note: candidates are: std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<object>& std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<object>::operator=(const std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<object>&)
drawing.h:110: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ in ‘it != ((object*)this)->object::objects. std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::end [with _Tp = object, _Alloc = std::allocator<object>]()’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_tree.h:292: note: candidates are: bool std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator!=(const std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>&) const [with _Tp = object]
drawing.h:111: error: ‘struct std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<object>’ has no member named ‘sketch’
```

here's my code:

```
void draw_in_place()
        {
            place();
            std::set<object>::const_iterator it;
            for(it = objects.begin(); it != objects.end(); it++){
                *it.draw_in_place();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
((object*)this)->object::objects. std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin
```

`objects` is apparently a `std::vector<object>`, not a `std::set<object>`.  You therefore need to use a `std::vector<object>::const_iterator`.

```
*it.draw_in_place();
```

This is incorrect:  you need to dereference the iterator to access the element first, then use the element:

```
(*it).draw_in_place();
// or
it->draw_in_place();
```

Comment: @Fred:  Yes, or you can use `->`.  (I always use `(*it).` instead of `it->` for iterators.  Don't ask why:  I don't know.  I do think it makes uses of an iterator stand out a bit more, but that's only a personal opinion)

Answer (score 2):

I think (at least) one of your problems is this line:

```
*it.draw_in_place();
```

The compiler is interpreting this as

```
*(it.draw_in_place());
```

versus your intended

```
(*it).draw_in_place();
```

To fix this, consider using the arrow operator, as in

```
it->draw_in_place();
```

It's perfectly legal to store custom objects in an STL set, so long as they can be compared with the `<` operator by default.  If they can't, you'll either need to define `operator <` on them, or provide a custom comparator to the `set`, or specialize `std::less` for your particular type.

Comment: Please, please overload op< rather than specialize std::less for your type.  It would be very confusing to have std::less do something different than the actual < operator.

Comment: @Fred Nurk- Seconded!  I just mentioned `std::less` for completeness. :-)